# How is this code snippet swapping Queue contents (Java)?

Tags: java, reference, queue, swap

Here's the code I wrote:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Why is this snippet actually swapping? 
    Queue<Integer> q1 = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<>();
    q1.add(10); q1.add(20); q1.add(30);
    q2.add(11); q2.add(22); q2.add(33);
    System.out.println("q1 before name swap --> " + q1);
    System.out.println("q2 before name swap --> " + q2);
    Queue<Integer> temp = q1;
    q1 = q2;
    q2 = temp;
    System.out.println("q1 after name swap --> " + q1);
    System.out.println("q2 after name swap --> " + q2);
}
```

Here's the output I got:

```
q1 before name swap --> [10, 20, 30]   
q2 before name swap --> [11, 22, 33]   
q1 after name swap --> [11, 22, 33]  
q2 after name swap --> [10, 20, 30]
```

Even after pondering over this for quite some time, I can't seem to understand why this code actually swaps the Queues. Shouldn't temp also store q2 contents, as I've written `temp = q1` and then `q1 = q2`? That is, shouldn't changes to q1 reflect on temp as well, since Queue is non-primitive/reference data type in Java?

Comment: Lets say q1 references object A, q2 object B. Then after `temp = q1` temp and q1 reference object A, q2 object B. After `q1 = q2` temp still references A, q1 and q2 reference B. After `q2 = temp` temp and q2 reference A, q1 references B.

Comment: @DietmarHöhmann Thanks, got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queues are indeed Non-primitive or Reference Data Type.

There are 3 Queues (q1, q2 & temp) here in the sample.

You do the following

- You assign q1 to [10, 20, 30] and q2 to [11, 22, 33]. The value of q1 and q2 is stored in memory.
- You then assign temp to q1 and temp value is now [10, 20, 30]. At this point of time if you modify temp or q1 then both of them will change.
- You then assign q1 to q2 and q1 starts pointing to reference of q2 and now q1 value is [11, 22, 33]
- You then assign q2 to temp and q2 starts pointing to reference of temp and now q2 value is [10, 20, 30]

You are basically changing references using q1=q2 and q2=temp and not the value.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, I finally understood what's happening.